# Сохранение форматирования таблицы при раскрытии новых элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Необходимо реализовать таблицу, по клику на строку которой появляется/исчезает подтаблица. Решил это реализовать с помощью события JQuery, которое будет сворачивать элементы.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#report').on("click", "tr.table-row", function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.table-row').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

```css
.tbl-qa {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.tbl-qa th.table-header {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tbl-qa .table-row td {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}

.tr.table-row {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="report" class="tbl-qa">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-header" width="6%">Номер</th>
      <th class="table-header">Код</th>
      <th class="table-header">Название</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="table-row">
      <td>Номер</td>
      <td>Код</td>
      <td>Название</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none" class="table-row2">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
```

Вопрос в том, как сохранить статичное форматирование  и   ? То есть что бы при раскрытии   таблица не разъезжалась.

Comment: У вас в последней строке 5 столбцов, а в первых двух - по три. Если добавить в строках где название `<td colspan="3">Название</td>` ничего не разъезжается.

Comment: Пришел к этому пару минут назад. Действительно так, спасибо!